# Flex Nested Drag And Drop

Tags: apache-flex

i have a canvas where i can add layout say another canvas.So both the canvas have drag enter and drag drop event .  I want to toggle this events .. i.e when outer canvas will accept drag inner will not accept and when inner will accept drag outer will not.I am facing a problem in nested drop events..Inner drop event is not working..Please help me out..Waiting for your help

Answer (score 0):

Use the DragManager class and add and remove event listeners as needed.